# How can I use Qt's Signal and Slots to implement dependency injection

Tags: qt, orm, dependency-injection, signals-slots

I have been looking for an approach to dependency injection, I recently stated  using Qt in order to take advantage of an ORM and I came across Signals and Slots.

The wiring in my application is designed to change completely every few seconds everything is modular.  This seems like a great match.

Can I approach the Signals and Slots from a DI view? How?  If not what are the strengths of Signals and Slots in comparison with a c++ di frameworking like dicpp or deepp http://sourceforge.net/projects/deepp/

In light of the fact that I will be using QxOrm with a SQLite in almost all functions, is one preferable?

Any tutorials or thoughts on how to handle the wiring for an app that will be dependent on its ability to expand, would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Late response but better late than never:

It is unclear to me what you meant by approaching signals and slots from the view of dependency injection.

Fundamentally, dependency injection is passing all the parameters that a type needs in its constructor. The Guice website has a more science-y explanation.

Signals and slots are ways of notifying components that something interesting has happened.

At the core, these two things are mostly orthogonal. That is, you don't use constructors to signal changes in the system, you would use constructors to create types that reflect the state of the system.

So I'd have to see code or a design before I can say what you should be doing.

Answer (score 0):

Even later of an answer but might help someone.

The answer is YES! You absolutely can use signals/slots in Qt instead of the Dependency Injection approach. Personally, I would even prefer it. Here's why.

Dependency Injection somewhat hinges on using interfaces or abstract representation of the objects you are injecting (otherwise you will not achieve dependency inversion, and then what's the point). In larger applications this gets so confusing and hard to maintain that you actually need a DI framework to help you keep order. On the other hand, for every class you need to inject, you have an interface. And for me, the existence of an interface implies that there are more than one implementation of said interface. Which is kind of true if you look at it together with your unit tests, but not looking at the application itself. Another point of confusion.

Even if this doesn't sound like it, I'm a big fan of dependency inversion, of which dependency injection is an implementation.

Using signals and slots in Qt you can achieve the same thing and even more. But you asked for an example:

Let's imagine we need two objects. A worker object, that does something and another object, a log object. As you can imagine were this is going, the worker object needs a reference to the log object, to log stuff.

Without either DI or signals/slots, you'd do it like this:

```
class Worker {
public:
  void doWork() {
    // Do some work
    m_log.log("Did some work");
  }

private:
  Log m_log;
};
```

Now obviously this is bad, as you have coupled Log and Worker together, you can't test Worker on its own etc.

OK, with dependency injection we would pass an interface pointer ILog into the Worker:

```
class Worker {
public:
  Worker(ILog *log): m_log{log} {}
  
  void doWork() {
    // Do some work
    m_log->log("Did some work.");
  }

private:
  ILog *m_log;
};
```

OK, better. Worker isn't depending on a particular implementation of a Log class, we can test it by mocking away ILog, and so on.

Now let's see how we could accomplish it using signals and slots. The Log class would implement a log slot:

```
class Log : public Object {
Q_OBJECT
public slots:
  void log(const QString &message) {
    // Do the logging...
  }
};
```

And the Worker class has a signal indicating it wishes to log:

```
class Worker : public Object {
Q_OBJECT
public:
  void doWork() {
    // Do some work
    emit log("Did some work");
  }

signals:
  void log(const QString &message);
};
```

And somewhere in another method, for example `main()`, you would "connect" those two together:

```
QObject::connect(&worker, &Worker::log, &log, &Log::log);
```

And that's it. Now you have the same functionality you did in the first two examples, but in this one, the Worker class doesn't even contain a pointer to a log, nor an interface. Nothing. It won't get any more decoupled than that. And as a side bonus, you just made it thread safe, should Worker and Log objects exist in different threads.

You can test Worker without mocking anything, using something like a QSignalSpy you can check if the log signal is emitted.

Using Signal and Slots and the reflection API that comes with Qt, you could even automate this connection or make it happen automatically, like a DI framework would.

I hope this view helps to inspire someone one day :)